# Having trouble interpreting the results DSolve gives for the Laguerre equation

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am trying to solve a second order ODE using *Mathematica*. Before I get into solving my (more complicated) problem, I am trying to use DSolve on known ODEs to check that the answer that *Mathematica* returns is what I expect.

Wolfram MathWorld lists the Laguerre differential equation as

$\quad \quad x y'' + (1 - x)y' + \lambda y = 0$

But then when I input

```
DSolve[x*y''[x] + (1 - x)*y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

I get in return

```
{{y[x] -> (-1 + x) C[1] + 
C[2] (-E^x - ExpIntegralEi[x] + x ExpIntegralEi[x])}}
```

Which at first glance looks nothing like the form of the Laguerre polynomials. Then, when I ask *Mathematica*,

```
?ExpIntegralEi
```

It tells me simply

> ExpIntegralEi[z] gives the exponential integral function Ei(z).

And there is no further information on the function Ei(z).

Now, my first guess would be that Ei(z) is just the Mathematica syntax for $e^{iz}$. But I still don't see how that relates to the Laguerre Polynomials, outside of the chance that the constants $C[1]$ and $C[2]$ could be, themselves, functions of x, and therefore could be the Lageurre polynomials.

So my first question is, "What the heck am I doing wrong?". But more specifically, I would like to know what I need to do to this expression to get the answer I'm looking for, and why it is that Mathematica is currently giving me nonsense (or so I think).

In general, I wonder if *Mathematica* is properly equipped and optimized to solve such ODEs (or to put it another way, perhaps using *Mathematica* is not the optimal route, and I would be better served trying to tackle the problem in, say, Matlab, for example).

Comment: The Laguerre polynomial solution to this DE is `LaguerreL[1, x]`, which is the polynomial `1 - x`, i.e. the negative of the one multiplied by `C[1]`.

Comment: Okay, so Mathematica returns the first Laguerre polynomial as a possible solution. But is it not true that _any_ Laguerre polynomial is a solution to the above DE? Why does it not give any information indicating that is the case? And I am still no closer to figuring out what is going on with the ExpIntegralEi[] functions...

Thank you for your help, though! It's good to know I'm not totally wrong here...

Comment: Try `DSolve[x*y''[x] + (1 - x)*y'[x] + λ y[x] == 0, y[x], x]`.  The `LaguerreL` is one of the two independent solutions and the `ExponentialEi` term is another for the case `λ == 1`.  Also try executing `LaguerreL[1, x]`.

Comment: Excellent! Now I get `{{y[x] -> C[1] HypergeometricU[-B, 1, x] + C[2] LaguerreL[B, x]}}` which is just the general solution expressed in terms of a linear combination of the two independent solutions.

Comment: The symbolic constants are independent of the independent variable, that is to say, they cannot be functions of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to know the mathematics you are dealing with as well as the related areas of *Mathematica* to understand what is going on. If you had read the MathWorld article carefully and looked up Laguerre in the Documentation Center (as I did) you would realize that you have done nothing wrong; you code is finding what you are looking for. You just don't realize you are getting a more general solution than you were expecting.

The general solution has two parts: a confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind and a Laquerre polynonial. In your solution, `C[2]` is the multiplier for the hypergeometric part, so you can ignore by setting `C[2]` to zero. `C[1]` should be set to `(-1)^k/k!` for the k-th polynomial

```
laguerre[k_] := 
  Collect[(DSolve[x*y''[x] + (1 - x)*y'[x] + k y[x] == 0, y[x], x] /. 
    {C[1] ->((-1)^k/k!), C[2] -> 0})[[1, 1, 2]], x]
a = Table[laguerre[i], {i, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1 - x, 1 - 2 x + x^2/2, 1 - 3 x + (3 x^2)/2 - x^3/6}
> ```

To check that this is correct, I will use the built-in function[`LaguerreL`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaguerreL.html).

```
b = Table[LaguerreL[i, x], {i, 3}]
```

> ```
>  {1 - x, 1/2 (2 - 4 x + x^2), 1/6 (6 - 18 x + 9 x^2 - x^3)}
> ```

```
Simplify[a - b]
```

> ```
>  {0, 0, 0}
> ```